# List of objects inside same model vs Factory vs Service

Tags: c#, comparative-review

I am creating a simple Country class. This Country have list of know countries. we can get the list of known countries `Country.AllCountries`,

```
public class Country
{
    static Country()
    {
        AllCountries = GetAllCountries();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alpha2Code { get; set; }
    public static List<Country> AllCountries { get; private set; }

    private static List<Country> GetAllCountries()
    {
        return new List<Country>
        {
            new Country{Alpha2Code = "BD", Name =  "Bangladesh"},
            // .........
        };
    }
}
```

I can also do the same using CountryService,

```
public class CountryService
{
    public List<Country> GetAllCountries()
    {
        // use cache instead
        return new List<Country>
        {
            new Country{Alpha2Code = "BD", Name =  "Bangladesh"},
            // ....
        };
    }
}
```

Or I can use a **Factory**. What should most of developers are doing for doing this type of work.

Comment: Go with the service so it wouldn't be treated as a child/parent reference, this would be more safer and appropriate. Using a service, would also keep the business logic intact. I don't see any need for a factory.

Comment: This requires a lot of context, namely on what data, how much data, how volatile it is, any performance considerations, ... The answers can range from a simple hardcoded in-memory static property, to a config file of varying sorts, to a networked data store. There is no "one true answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By separating the `Country` dto class from `CountryService` / `CountryProvider` / `Countries` allows us to address some concerns on the latter one.

Some design concerns:

- The country names and codes are changing fairly rarely that's why storing them only once gives good performance if you want to frequently access them
- They are not allowed to change (without redeployment) we have to express this immutability via the type system as well
- There are many countries so it would make sense to populate the collection when it is first needed

Here is a solution which addresses all concerns:

```
public static class Countries
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ImmutableArray<Country>> countries = new Lazy<ImmutableArray<Country>>(() => InitWellKnownCountries(), true);
    public static ImmutableArray<Country> WellKnownOnes = countries.Value;

    private static ImmutableArray<Country> InitWellKnownCountries()
        => new[]
        {
            new Country{Alpha2Code = "AL", Name =  "Albania"},
            new Country{Alpha2Code = "BD", Name =  "Bangladesh"},
            ...
        }.ToImmutableArray();
}
```

- We have used `static` everywhere to ensure to have a single instance
- We have used `ImmutableArray` to prevent the collection change (`Country` properties still can change)
- We have used `Lazy` to ensure a deferred population in a thread-safe manner

In order to prevent `Country` instance modification after initialization you can take advantage of [C# 9's init](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init):

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string Alpha2Code { get; init; }
}
```

---

I also want to emphasise one more thing. This kind of separation allows you to replace the hard coded value to dynamically retrieved ones by

- reading and parsing a json file
- fetching and parsing from a database
- calling and parsing an API
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use is Provider as in ICountryProvider, and I would expect it to be provided to the classes that use it via dependency injection.  Of course that doesn’t have to be the case, you could create the interface and apply it manually.  But I would consider your first example a code smell as it would tie the concept of Country too closely with the concept “get countries”.

Using a Service as in your second example is better, but to make it flexible you still need to create an interface.  What if I wanted to make a change so that I could get countries that existed in 1903? With your first example you have to change Country and you really can’t provide more than one implementation without rewriting things.  With your second example, you are missing the interface, but it could be made to work, but I believe the term Service carries with it some unwanted implications.  For one thing I would generally expect it to return the **same** list across invocations, which means that I wouldn’t expect it to sometimes be a list from 1903 and sometimes a list from 2021.

A ICountryProvider is just right, there isn’t really a lot of implications around how countries are picked or where the data comes from.  Its as close to an injected collection of countries as you can get, without actually injecting the countries.  Which is probably what you want.